# Custom field FB02 SAPMF05L Dynpro 1710

Tags: abap, sap-erp

I've added a new custom field (appen BKPF) in FB01 screen (dynpro 0100) and populating it in BKPF table. It's working fine.

Then I added the same field on dympro 1710 (Document Header Data) in FB02 and I set the field in OB32 to be able to edit it.

The problem is that when I change the value of the custom field in FB02 and save the document, the value is lost and does not update zfield on the BKPF table.

How can I solve? Why does it work correctly in FB01 and does it not work in FB02?

You could help me have a solution for this.

Thanks for your help.

Alberto

Comment: Give the exact steps you've done for FB02, and for FB01 preferably too, and screenshots, please.

Comment: Hi SunCatcher, in FB01 I changed only the dympro 0100 and work correctly in FB02 i've using the same procedure but the table not updating when saving the document.

Comment: It would be helpful if you indicate what exit o BADi are you using for FB01 and FB02.